# Error: invalid_client Application: Project Default Service Account

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

My google + Sign in button is throwing this error. What should I do.
I have already changed my app name, redirect url and scope.

Thank you!

Comment: I have solved it by changing the client id and the origin url..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by changing the client id and the origin url..